# Windows Phone 8 System Tray not appearing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

This is my code in the cs file. I have the exact same code when getting location at a different place and it works and Im able to see the progress bar. For getting location Im wrapping an async method in the system tray and it works. Coming to this Winodow for displaying photos Im unable to see the progress indicator on top of the current page what so ever. Here is a piece of code that I have. In xaml I also have shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True".Please help why the progress bar dosent show up. Does progress bar only work with async? This is not entire code but just the piece that I have problem. Thanks.

```
public DisplayPhotos()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Getting Photos";
    DisplayPhotos.SetprogressIndicator(true);
    Display(); //Not an async method.
    DisplayPhotos.SetprogressIndicator(false);  
}

private static void SetprogressIndicator(bool value)
{
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = value;
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically you will not see any UI updates that are made and then reverted in a single non-async function call. The UI only updates once per "tick" so if you both show and hide the UI in the same function then it will never be shown. For more info on the concept of how UI doesn't update during synchronous processing, see [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms741870(v=vs.100).aspx#samples)(it is written for WPF, but applies for XAML in general):

Note that this isn't *strictly* true, for example independent animations happen on a separate thread, but it's a general rule of thumb.

Also I'd be careful about setting the `ProgressIndicator` in your page's constructor, since it will fail in certain situations (I think if it is the first page created in the app). You should wait until after the page has been loaded to show / hide the indicator.

Comment: I tried doing it in the loaded event but still it dosent appear. Do I need to start a new thread for the Display method. Thanks.

Comment: You need to let the OS do some work on the UI thread - running your code inside a `Task` will help. Moving away from the constructor and to the `Loaded` event might cause you other issues (I would use `OnNavigatedTo` override and make sure I don't reload the content of it's already loaded).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you will not find UI changes or some heavy method call working in constructor. It is always advisable to put some light code e.g: event registration in constructor.

Please refer following code block, It may help you.

```
    public Page1() 
    {
      InitializeComponent(); 
      this.Loaded += Page1_Loaded; 
    } 
    void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
      SystemTray.IsVisible = true; 
      SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator(); 
      SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Islndeterminate = true; 
      SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = true; 
      Display(); 
      SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = false; 
    }
```

In loaded event, you can use async function call also.

== UPDATE ==

Lets try with another ways as above code work for me. Please try using xaml also (just for cross check)

```
shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="Black"
shell:SystemTray.ForegroundColor="White"
shell:SystemTray.Opacity="1"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
<shell:ProgressIndicator
Text="Waiting"
IsIndeterminate="True"
IsVisible="True" />
</shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
```

Put this code in your page to just formally check that it is not anything else that causes the error.

Second, Please try following code if above at code side. You should implement either from these at a time.

```
ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator
{
    IsVisible = true,
    IsIndeterminate = true,
    Text = "Downloading details..."
};
SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, progress);
```

Just for clear understanding, hope you are building windows phone 8 app only and also implemented all other stuff properly.

Just for knowledge, your "Display" method should take some time to execute because if it executes very fast then ProgressIndicator might not be visible.

And yes, for testing purpose, you can take dispatcher to take separate UI thread.

Comment: I tried doing it in the loaded event but still it dosent appear. Do I need to start a new thread for the Display method. Thanks.

Comment: Nikhil, check the update in answer. If possible , make constructor lighter.